# slightly fidgeting data that is equal

Tags: python

I am reading a csv line by line. The CSV looks like this:

```
29.781646
29.781646
42.698079
43.346914
44.369203
45.006459
45.006459
39.316758
```

When two numbers are exactly the same I would like to change one slightly.

For example there are two values that are `29.781646` and I would like to change one to be `29.781645`

If the csv contains:

```
29.781646
29.781646
29.781646
```

then I would like to change it to:

```
29.781646
29.781645
29.781644
```

I would very much appreciate your guidance, on implementing this efficiently.

Please note that I want to do this in multiples of `0.000001`

Comment: Do you always want to decrease the value?

Comment: @deadly it doesnt matter to me, as long as they're different

Comment: Ok. And do you want to write the numbers back to the CSV file?

Comment: i am reading the csv into a variable, so i want to write the values back to the variable and then back to the csv

Comment: Modifying a float many times gives different results. `1.2345 - 1000 * .0001` returns `1.1344999999999998`. However, `a = 1.2345; for i in xrange(1000): a -= .0001` returns `1.134500000000011`, which is not the same number.

Comment: You can use `decimal` instead of float, or just multiply the values with 1000000, work with `int`, and the divide by 1000000 again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just iterate over the file line by line, and keep track of seen values using a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set), decreasing the value if it is already in the [`set`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set).

rough example:

```
seen = set()
with open('test.csv') as input, open('test_out.csv', 'w') as output:
    for line in input:
        value = float(line)
        while value in seen:
            value -= 0.000001
        seen.add(value)
        output.write(str(value) + '\n')
```

This is efficent since a `set` offers a O(1) lookup

---

If you're going to write the values back to the same file anyway, you can use the fileinput module:

```
import fileinput

seen = set()
for line in fileinput.FileInput('test.csv', inplace=True):
    value = float(line)
    while value in seen:
        value -= 0.000001
    seen.add(value)
    print str(value).strip()
```

**EDIT**

To address eumiro's comment about the floating point issue:

You can use the [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) modules `Decimal` or just multiply/divide the value with/by `1000000` to work with `int` instead of using `float`. As I wrote, this is just a rough example :-)

Comment: Clever check, unfortunately does not work well if there are too many "consecutive" numbers. See my comment to the question.

Comment: The same idea could be used with the set, but instead of changing the value many times over in a loop, keep the original value and change the modifier instead .

Comment: What do you think about my answer 90% based on yours?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = """29.781646
29.781646
42.698079
43.346914
44.369203
45.006459
45.006459
39.316758
"""
>>> d = {}
>>> for nb in [float(l) for l in s.split('\n') if l]:
    # Create a dict of repetitions, to decrease by the number of times already seen
    if nb not in d:
        d[nb] = 0
        print nb
    else:
        rep = d[nb]
        d[nb] = rep + 1
        print nb - d[nb] * 0.000001


29.781646
29.781645
42.698079
43.346914
44.369203
45.006459
45.006458
39.316758
>>>
```

Comment: Well, no, it doesn't, but I copied the bad output (I ran it twice without resetting the dict :). Output changed, thanks !

Comment: looks great! can you please explain this line for nb in [float(l) for l in s.split('\n') if l]:

Answer (score 1):

Based on BigYellowCactus but addresses eumiro's comment about how errors accumulate in floats which are modified many times:

```
seen = set() with open('test.csv') as input, open('test_out.csv', 'w') as output:
    for line in input:
        value = float(line)
        modifier = 1

        while True
            new_value = value - (modifier * 0.000001)
            modifier += 1
            if not new_value in seen:
                break

        seen.add(new_value)
        output.write(str(value) + '\n')
```